Theorem Du Bois-Reymond
Theorem Du Bois-Reymond. A bounded function $f$ is integrable over $R$ if and only if
$$ \forall \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists \delta > 0 \quad \forall \mathcal{Z} \text{ with } \Phi(\mathcal{Z}) < \delta: \quad O(\mathcal{Z}) - U(\mathcal{Z}) < \varepsilon. $$
Proof. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $\tilde{\mathcal{Z}}$ be a sequence of partititions $(\tilde{\mathcal{Z}}_k)_{k \geq 1}$ with $\Phi(\tilde{\mathcal{Z}}_k) \to 0$. This partition is formed by a grid that, within the interior of $R$, has boundaries of length $L = (\tilde{N} - 1)(d - c) + (\tilde{M} - 1)(b - a)$. Let $\mathcal{Z}$ be another partition with $\Phi(\mathcal{Z}) < \delta$. The total content of those rectangles from $\mathcal{Z}$ that have a non-empty intersection with the inner boundaries of the partition $\tilde{\mathcal{Z}}$ is bounded by $L \cdot \delta$. Hence, for $-C \leq f(x) \leq C$, we obviously have
$$ O(\mathcal{Z}) - U(\mathcal{Z}) \leq O(\tilde{\mathcal{Z}}) - U(\tilde{\mathcal{Z}}) + L \cdot \delta \cdot 2C = \varepsilon + L \cdot \delta \cdot 2C, $$
and the assertion follows.
Question. I’m trying to understand the proof, but I’m struggling with the sentence: "The total content of those rectangles from $\mathcal{Z}$ that have a non-empty intersection with the inner boundaries of the partition $\tilde{\mathcal{Z}}$ is bounded by $L \cdot \delta$. Could anyone provide clarification or a more detailed explanation of why this is the case? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
